# Error with systemd-shim package after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, systemd

After running the installation package, the following errors appear:

```
Shim for systemd
systemd-shim
Try to send a bug report
installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
```

I was loading software and the uploading failed with this error message:

```
(Reading database ... 1684754 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd by systemd-shim'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
  different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
 installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-shim
```

Comment: You may wish to clarify the version number of the OS.  Is this 18.04?

Comment: I think yes. The automatic software updater suggested to upgrade to the new version and I have said yes